# How to show factorial in expanded form with variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions

When evaluating the following

```
(Factorial[n + 1]/Factorial[(n + 1) - (k + 1)])
```

with Mathematica 9, the result is sent to output as

```
(1 + n)!/((n + 1) - (k + 1))!
```

I would like to show the [expanded](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Expand.html) (if that's the correct term) form of the result , if possible, to show for example

```
(n + 1)n(n - 1)...(n+1-k)
```

Is there a function like `Expand` to accomplish this?

Comment: Think again about what do you want as a result. `...` isn't valid syntax in Mathematica

Comment: How would you know the bounds for the expansion?  What exactly do you want for output?

Comment: Your indeterminate product can be represented `Product[i, {i, n + 1 - k, n + 1}]`, but `Product` evaluates to `Pochhammer[1 - k + n, 1 + k]`.  One could perhaps format `Pochhammer` to display as you wish.  Would that be what you're after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a nonstandard syntax but it can be easily implemented with `UpValues`

```
FactorialExpand[expr_] := 
   expr /. Binomial[n_, k_] :> n!/k!/(n - k)! /. Factorial[x_] :> ProductSequence[1, x];

ProductSequence /: ProductSequence[a_, b1_]/ProductSequence[a_, b2_] :=
   ProductSequence[b2 + 1, b1];

MakeBoxes[ProductSequence[a_, b_], StandardForm] ^:= 
 RowBox[{MakeBoxes[#1 #2], "...", MakeBoxes[#3 #4]}] &[a, a + 1, b - 1, b];

(1 + n)!/((n + 1) - (k + 1))! // FactorialExpand
```

> ```
> (1 - k + n) (2 - k + n) ... n (1 + n)
> ```

I also add `Binomial` expansion

```
Binomial[n, k] // FactorialExpand
```

> ```
> ((1 + k) (2 + k) ... (-1 + n) n)/(1 2 ... (-1 - k + n) (-k + n))
> ```