# Series for $(1+x)^{m}$ with specific notation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, series-expansion

I'm trying to get mathematicas series function for $(1+x)^{m}$ to output a result that look like this:

$(1+x)^{m} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{m !}{n !(m-n) !}x^{n}$

However,

```
Clear["Global`*"];
series[expr_, x_, x0_] := 
 Defer[expr = Sum[#, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]] &[
  FullSimplify@
    SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, n}, 
     Assumptions -> {n >= 0}] (x - x0)^n]
series[(1 + x)^m, x, 0]
```

> $(1+x)^{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$ Binomial $[m, n]$

How can I get the form without special function `Binomial[m,n]`?

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}$ Binomial $[m, n] ---> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{m !}{n !(m-n) !}x^{n}$

I know that this result can be achieved by slightly modifying the code, but I have tried and can't do it yet.

Comment: "but I have tried and can't do it yet" Then what did you try?

Comment: @xzczd Because `FunctionExpand[Binomial[m, n]]==Gamma[1 + m]/(Gamma[1 + m - n] Gamma[1 + n])`, so I modified some code in `ComplexityFunction -> ((LeafCount@# + 
     10 Count[#, _Gamma | _Pochhammer, {0, \[Infinity]}]) &)`. But I can't get the result.

Comment: `(Binomial[m, n] // FunctionExpand[#] &) /. 
  Gamma[1 + a_] :> Factorial[a] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Hint: the assumption is not enough.

Comment: Simply define a rule:  `your expression /. Binomial[m_, n_] -> m!/(n! (m - n)!)`

Comment: @Syed I believe `Gamma[a_] :> Factorial[a-1]` is more robust (e.g. works on `Gamma[2+n]` and `Gamma[n]` etc.). Alternatively, one could simply write the rule to transform `Binomial` into factorials directly.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100409/show-factorial-instead-of-gamma-in-the-result-of-rsolve, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265163/series-for-sinx-with-specific-notation, and possibly https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/how-to-show-factorial-in-expanded-form-with-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bitofac[test_] := test /. Binomial[n_, k_] -> n!/k!/(n - k)!
series[expr_, x_, x0_] := 
 Defer[expr = Sum[#, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]] &[
   FullSimplify@
     SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, n}, 
      Assumptions -> {n >= 0}] (x - x0)^n] // bitofac
series[(1 + x)^m, x, 0]
```

> [image: res]

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, OP fails to understand the hint, so:

```
series[expr_, x_, x0_] := 
 Defer[expr = Sum[#, {n, 0, ∞}]] &[
  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {m >= n >= 0 && {n, m} ∈ Integers}] &@
    FunctionExpand@SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, x0, n}] (x - x0)^n]
series[(1 + x)^m, x, 0]
```